# Position of "dich" when translating 'I can't wait to see you next month'

Tags: english-to-german, grammaticality

I'm trying to say

> I can't wait to see you next month.

> Ich kann es nicht erwarten, dich nächsten Monat zu sehen.

I'm not sure if I have put *dich* in the correct place.

Comment: What makes you uncertain if it is right or wrong?

Comment: Because I'm a beginner so I'm just uncertain about everything haha

Comment: It is natural that you are uncertain the moment you do not know. Just I cannot read any meaning that is not written there. So any hint helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, this is correct.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann es kaum erwarten, dich nächsten Monat zu sehen.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do you think your answer would be a bit more understandable if you explain why "dich" should be located where you wrote? So that other people are able to understand similiar examples/situations?

Comment: Thanks, why would you put 'kaum' rather than 'nicht' ?